# Careers: distance in kilometers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

I understand that Careers is mainly targetted to the US market, or at least the majority of job offers are in the USA I guess, so displaying the job offer's distance in miles makes a lot sense. However given that Careers is also open to the rest of the world it makes more sense to actually use an [internationally understood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system) way to display these things.

As such I would like to request that the distance is being shown in *kilometers*, or at least suggest that a setting is added to change the way distances are displayed.

Comment: Furlongs are also needed.

Comment: The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from!

Comment: @Adam Davis: Doesn't change the fact that the rest of the world actually uses the metric system and understands kilometers more easily than miles ;)

Comment: @Adam: The US system is _not_ a standard!

Comment: @yoda We loved the metric system before it went all commercial.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point, but as you say Careers is currently very US centric, so using kilometers alone wouldn't really fit, either.

I would suggest using both, in the form of

```
 20 miles (32 km)
```

Comment: maybe instead of **20 miles (32 km)** it could say **20 miles or 32 km** to appease the masses.

Comment: @Changeling that just seems like a wordier/confusing version of the suggested form

Comment: I fear this way lies madness. Not only is it less readable, but it's also clearly Wrong — it should be `32 km (20 miles)`.

Comment: @Gilles nah. Look at the distribution of jobs on careers, probably 90% of them are in the US. I'm comfortable with any format as long as the km are *there*

Answer (score 3):

It would be lighter on the UI to display a single distance, based on some localization information. Since the localization is available right there…

Show `20 miles` if the location is in the US (and perhaps a few other countries — is Myanmar still using British units for distances?). Show `32 km` in the rest of the world.

Comment: I would have thought offering it as a user preference makes more sense. I hate it when websites "assume" my localisation preferences based on my IP. Britain uses both miles and km, and it's totally personal preference.

Comment: @Blowski: There's no need to bring IP location (which I hate too), since the information to display is inherently localized. Agreed, some countries are in transition, but a preference is not something you'll get on SE (Jeff is very much against customizable UIs).

Comment: In which case @Pekka's response below is a good balance. Or something like in the same "neighbourhood", "city", "state", "country" might be useful.

Comment: @Blowski: It's hard to define such things though..